# How to redirect all urls of media files to new format widthout date in htaccess (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

There is old website with this kind of media url format:
`https://website.com/wp-content/ulopads/2022/14/file-name.jpg`

Content from this page will be rewritten. The files will have the same names but a different address. The date will be removed. The new file address will look like this:
`https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/file-name.jpg`

How to write a redirect that is universal for all image and media files?

I'm trying something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but its not working

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `wp-content/` or `wp-content/uploads/` ?

Comment: i have .htaccess inside public_html main folder.

Comment: Then make sure this redirect rule is right at the top just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: That is it! I put it below wordpress redirections part before. Now when it is on the top it's working. Thanks.